# C++ async get data from other function

Tags: c++, asynchronous, arduino, uart

This is not a coding, but mostly architectural question...

For example, I have a `loop()` function, in which I get data from some source (UART in my case). The code is pretty much like this (pseudocode):

```cpp
loop() {
  auto data = UART.GetData();
  // differ data from each other and push it to corresponding message queue or golang-style channel?
  Console.Print(data);
}
```

I need to implement an async REST HTTP function, which will book (order) data from UART and wait for it to come. Keep in mind, that other async REST HTTP functions may request data from UART at this moment as well. The code of async REST HTTP function will be like this:

```cpp
handler(AsyncRequest &req) {
  UART.RequestNeededData(); // This function returns nothing. Data will be handled in loop() method
  auto data = // somehow get this data from other method, in this case it's loop() (get data from message queue or Golang-style channel?)
  req.SendDataToClient(data);
}
```

UART operates its own protocol to differ requested data and responses. Treat it like req/res packets. I need to pass requested data from `handler()` function back to `handler()`.

Hope you understood what I need to do and can assist me with this problem. Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.  Also, *"pass requested data from handler() function back to handler()"* is super confusing, why is "handler" used twice in this sentence?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the question is simple... how to implement this type of function-to-function messaging? Also handler used twice in sentence because you order data in handler and want to receive it in handler, but you can't simply wait for it, because there's many other handlers that order data too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with a queue template class:

```
 QueuePendingCommands<char> queue(100); //-> Max 100 chars in this queue
```

the handler initializes the appropriate queue and fills it with data

```
 auto data = UART.GetData();
 if (data = fullfillConditionA )
     if (data != '\n') 
        QueuePendingCommandsA.push(data);
     else
        processResponse(QueuePendingCommandsA);
  else if (data = fullfillConditionB )
     if (data != '\n') 
        QueuePendingCommandsB.push(data);
     else
        processResponse(QueuePendingCommandsB);
 else ....
```

In my case there is a defined final char (eg '#' or '\n'), pushing this into the queue triggers emptying the queue and fullfilling the response:

```
void processResponse (inQueue) {
/** Create response - Drain the queued up commands */
 while (inQueue.count() > 0) {
     strcat(response, inQueue.pop());
   }
 .... Do something with the response
 }
```

So for every request there is a defined queue you write to and the response is triggered after the special char is received (also a fixed number of chars, a condition or a timeout could trigger the emptying of the queue)